# Flex row of 5 divs, one with a static width, the other four with percentage

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a row with 5 columns. The first column is a profile picture that I want to remain at a constant 150px width. The other four have a variety of inputs/buttons, I want them each to be a % based and flex grow to fill up the remaining space, all the while the first column should persist at 150px.

My current setup is:

```
<div class="flex-row">
    <div class="column-1">content</div>
    <div class="column-2">content</div>
    <div class="column-3">content</div>
    <div class="column-4">content</div>
    <div class="column-5">content</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.flex-row {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.column-1 {
  width: 150px;
}
.column-2 {
  width: 20%;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
.column-3 {
  width: 25%;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
.column-4 {
  width: 20%;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
.column-5 {
  width: 15%;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

Now obviously this doesn't work but you can see what I'm going for. I'm using Sass so am happy to throw in some calculations in there. I tried doing something like 100% - 150px but couldn't quite figure out how to make it jive.

1) How do I create a 5 column layout with the 1st being static width and the remaining 4 being a percentage of the remaining width?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this modified layout, the first column (profile picture) is always 150px. The other four flex items distribute remaining space equally among themselves.

Here's all the CSS you need:

```
.flex-row { display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap; }
.column-1 { flex: 0 0 150px; }
.column-2 { flex: 1 1 auto; }
.column-3 { flex: 1 1 auto; }
.column-4 { flex: 1 1 auto; }
.column-5 { flex: 1 1 auto; }
```

DEMO: https://jsfiddle.net/mLtwmc62/17/

Same code with explanations:

```
.flex-row {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap; /* remove if you want to force all flex items on same row */
}

.column-1 {
    /* width: 150px; remove; use flex property instead */
    flex: 0 0 150px; /* don't grow, don't shrink, stay at 150px */
}

.column-2 {
   /* width: 20%; use flex-basis instead */
   /* flex-grow: 1; use flex property instead */
  flex: 1 1 auto; /* grow evenly, shrink evenly, start at natural width; see NOTES below */
}

.column-3 {
    /* width: 25%; */
    /* flex-grow: 1; */
    flex: 1 1 auto;
}

.column-4 {
    /* width: 20%; */
    /* flex-grow: 1; */
    flex: 1 1 auto;
}

.column-5 {
    /* width: 15%; */
    /* flex-grow: 1; */
    flex: 1 1 auto;
}
```

*NOTES:*

If you wish to apply unique widths to flex items (you have differing width percentages in your code), here are two options:

- use the [`flex-basis`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-basis) property, which is the third value in the [`flex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex) property. `flex-basis` sets the initial size of the flex item. So instead of `flex: 1 1 auto;` you can say `flex: 1 1 20%`.
- use the [`flex-grow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-grow) property (the first value in `flex`). `flex-grow` tells each flex item what proportion of the remaining space it should consume. Here's an example:

  ```
   .column-1 { flex: 0 0 150px; }
   .column-2 { flex: 2 1 auto; }
   .column-3 { flex: 5 1 auto; }
   .column-4 { flex: 3 1 auto; }
   .column-5 { flex: 1 1 auto; }
  ```

  DEMO: https://jsfiddle.net/mLtwmc62/18/

Comment: I see three rows when viewing this example, OP asked for one row.

Comment: @ryanpcmcquen Try expanding your browser window. Also, OP added `flex-wrap: wrap` in his code. In my notes above, I suggest removing it if he wants to keep all items on one row on smaller screens.

Comment: If you suggest removing it, then why not remove it in your answer/demo?

Comment: @ryanpcmcquen, the OP activated the wrap feature. That appears to be his preference. Why would I remove it? My suggestion, you will notice in my previous comment, is just an option I highlighted *if he wants to keep all items of one row*.